# Educational children's book about a young girl learning about computers in an Alice in Wonderland homage

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I was recently trying to track down a book I thought I'd bought as part of a Humble Bundle, so I read it in the last 10 years, probably closer to 5-6 years ago. The book was more didactic than story-based, with each chapter introducing a programming concept. More parable than fairy tale. It was short, less than 50 pages. I don't remember illustrations, but I feel like there would have had to have been. I thought the name was "Alice in Computerland" or something like that, but my searches on that name have turned up a number of nonmatching items such as *[Alicia's Miasadventures in Computer Land](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23609565-alicia-s-misadventures-in-computer-land)*. I'm going to keep poking around my Humble library, but 10 years of purchases, and a somewhat outdated interface, means the page keeps locking up on me.

The *Hello Ruby* series was suggested to me, but does not look like a match, as it's set in the real world with tasks rather than someone in a fantasy world. In my book, it is a fantasy world, and I think that the protagonist female specifically talks to characters like the Mock Turtle, with concepts like loops and branching being explained by the conversation and activities of the characters.

I also don't believe it is *[micro:bit in Wonderland](https://www.techagekids.com/p/alice.html)* as I don't remember it involving hardware, and it was more of a "knock off" Wonderland than a straight usage of Carroll's setting and characters.

Comment: Was it definitely programming related? There's an "Alice in Quantumland".

Comment: @qazmlpok: I am almost 100% certain it was about programming, maybe specifically algorithms. Her name might not have been "Alice", but the story definitely borrowed from the book's setting.

Comment: "Hello Ruby"? I backed this project because I have daughters and it promised to be an interesting introduction to programming. It definitely has illustrations.

Comment: @FredricShope: That looks vaguely familiar, but it's not in my library. I'll see if I can track down a copy. Maybe they just removed it at some point.

Comment: Listening to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZclTs81Zz2Y, it doesn't seem to match my memory.

Comment: Might it be one of the books listed on this site: https://www.alice.org/resources/alice-2-textbooks/?  These are text books for the 'Alice' children's programming language and it would be natural for them to use an Alice in Wonderland based theme.